# How to pass options to cp_r in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Can someone tell me how to pass `options` to Ruby `cp_r`? I want to set `:derefernce_root` to `false` so that if there is a broken symlink it still gets copied and `:preserve` to `true` to preserve the permissions.

I am thinking of somthing like this: `cp_r 'src/.', 'dest', options[:preserve] = 'p', options[:dereference_root] = false`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
FileUtils.cp_r 'src/.', 'dest', preserve: 'p', dereference_root: false
```

I don't know anything about those options and whether they are valid.  But that is the syntax you generally need to use to pass options to a Ruby method.  The last part will usually end up getting converted to a hash with keys `:preserve` and `:dereference_root`, and that hash will be passed as the last argument to the method.

Comment: Appreciate quick reponse. Will try it and post how it worked.